# How do I bind callbacks to a listbox using tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, callback, listbox

I'm playing around with tkinter and am struggling somewhat with the use of listboxes. I want to bind an arbitrary function to a selection event. As I understand it - it should go something like this.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        lb = tk.Listbox(self)
        lb.insert("end", "one")
        lb.insert("end", "two")
        lb.insert("end", "three")
        lb.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.OnDouble)
        lb.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    def OnDouble(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        selection=widget.curselection()
        value = widget.get(selection[0])
        print "selection:", selection, ": '%s'" % value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

My understanding is that when an element in the list box is double-clicked, a virtual event is created which can be bound to a callback function - in this case the OnDouble function defined.
I'm a little confused about the intricacies of this, would someone be able to explain exactly what is happening in this OnDouble function?

I'm trying to trigger an event when an element is selected from a listbox - i'm using pygubu to design the GUI but I understand that the syntax still follows tkinter conventions:

```
class TestApp:
def __init__(self):
    self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder()
    builder.add_resource_path(PROJECT_PATH)
    builder.add_from_file(PROJECT_UI)
    self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('toplevel_1')
    builder.connect_callbacks(self)
    self.box = builder.get_object('listbox_1')
    self.list = [1,2,3,4]
    self.box.insert(tk.END, self.list[0])
    self.box.insert(tk.END, self.list[1])
    self.box.insert(tk.END, self.list[2])
    self.box.insert(tk.END, self.list[3])
    self.console = builder.get_object('text_1')


def print_console(self, msg):
    self.console.configure(state="normal")
    self.console.insert(tk.END, msg+"\n")
    self.console.configure(state="disabled")
    self.console.update_idletasks()
    


def run(self):
    self.mainwindow.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = TestApp()
    app.run()
```

Essentially I want the console to print (using the defined command) something like f'You have selected number {number}' when said number is double clicked on the list box. How can I do this? I would appreciate the workings behind it, so I can apply it to more complex exercises, and understand the solution rather than just copy/paste it.

Comment: Are you specifically wanting the callback to be called on a double-click, or are you wanting the callback whenever an item is selected? There's more than one way to select an item in a listbox.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://tk-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/listbox/listbox.html#listboxselect-callback-function)

Comment: Double clicking was just a specific example of the problem really, yes whenever the item is selected is what I’m looking for, does this change how you would code the callback function?

Comment: Mabye it’s because I’m tired but I struggled to grasp the docs when I read them earlier, I’m trying to understand what’s happening in layman’s  terms really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items in a listbox can be selected with a single click, but they can also be selected via the keyboard. For this reason, binding to a specific physical event such as `<Double-1>` is not the best way to be notified when the selection changes.

In the specific case of the listbox, binding to `<<ListboxSelect>>` is the best event to bind to, as that event will be generated after the selection has been set regardless of how it was set.

For example:

```
lb.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.onSelect)
```

When a function is called via a binding it will automatically be passed an argument that contains details about the event that triggered the function call. One of the parameters is `widget`, which is a reference to the widget that received the call.

In your specific case you could ignore that and use `self.listbox` within the bound function, but using `event.widget` is a good habit to get into. That is why the code you copied starts with `widget = event.widget`

The next step is to get the selected item or items. In your case only a single selection is allowed at a time. However, the `curselection` method always returns a list. `selection[0]` will refer to the item selected, if there is a selection.

Note: the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event is triggered both when the selection is set or it is unset, so the code in your question could fail if the items are deselected by some means.

Finally, once you have the index of the selected item (eg: `selection[0]`), you can use that numerical index to get the text of the selected item. That is what the line `value = widget.get(selection[0])` is doing.