# Pressable list, using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

**Introduction**

Hello out there! Im a highschoolstudent tired of inserting formulas over and over again every time I need to calculate example show angel of fraction for instance. I've written a script that not only calculates this for me, but also prints it on a docx document. With this small program I go the idea of making a formal collection using tkinters as the plugin for a GUI. Ive made some progress, but can't seem to figure out how to make the list "clickable".Help would be greatly appreciated.

**Script for interface so far**

```
from tkinter import *

# Defines event and prints widget
def Scankey(event):
    val = event.widget.get()
    print(val)

    if val == '':
        data = list
    else:
        data = []
        for item in list:
            if val.lower() in item.lower():
                data.append(item)

    Update(data)

def Update(data):
    listbox.delete(0, 'end')

    # Makes list of data
    for item in data:
        listbox.insert('end', item)

list = ('Brydningsformel', 'Rydbergformel',)

ws = Tk()

entry = Entry(ws)
entry.pack()
entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', Scankey)

listbox = Listbox(ws)
listbox.pack()
Update(list)

ws.title("Formula")
ws.geometry('500x500+550+200')

ws.mainloop()
```

**Script for calculating angel of fraction**

```
import math
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches



def fb(v1,n1,n2):
    rv1 = math.radians(v1)
    i = math.sin(rv1)*n1/n2
    val = math.degrees(math.asin(i))

    p = document.add_paragraph('Beregning af brydningsvinkel')
    tekst = "Indfaldsvinkel "+ str(v1)+ ", n1= "+ str(n1)+ ", n2= "+ str(n2)
    p = document.add_paragraph(tekst)
    tekst = "Brydningsvinkel "+ str(val)
    p = document.add_paragraph(tekst)
    p = document.add_paragraph()



document = Document()

section = document.sections[0]
header = section.header
header



document.add_heading('Brydningsvinkler', 0)

p = document.add_paragraph('Beregningerne laves ved hjælp af schells lov. Dette har jeg skrevet et pythonscript til at udregne automatisk for mig.')
p = document.add_paragraph()

p.add_run('   def fb(v1,n1,n2):').bold=True
p = document.add_paragraph ()
p.add_run ('   rv1 = math.radians(v1)').bold=True
p = document.add_paragraph ()
p.add_run ('  i = math.sin(rv1)*n1/n2 ' ).bold=True
p = document.add_paragraph ()
p.add_run ('  val = math.degrees(math.asin(i)) ').bold=True
p = document.add_paragraph ()


fb(38,1.33,1)
fb(44,1.33,1.0)
fb(47,1.33,1.0)
fb(48.5,1.33,1.0)
fb(24,1.33,1.0)

paragraph = header.paragraphs[0]
paragraph.text = "Aske Frost"


document.save('demo.docx')
```

Comment: Do take in mind that I started trying to learn python a week ago, and therefore are no where close to being good. 
    comments about other places in the code that could be improved would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a *selection event* for the List box? Because that already exists in tkinter an can be found in a searching engine. Also calling tkinter `Update` meth should be avoided.

Comment: This should answer your question: [How do I bind callbacks to a listbox using tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860721/how-do-i-bind-callbacks-to-a-listbox-using-tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code, and I believe that you have created a search bar for a list. That's an awesome start!

## The problem

I think I understand that you want to make something happen whenever the user selects an option. To do that, you can define a callback as follows:

```py
def on_select(event):
    # event is a tkinter.Event
    listbox = event.widget

    # selection is a tuple containing the indices of all selected items, which could be empty
    selection = listbox.curselection()

    # Do nothing if there is nothing selected (i.e. selection is an empty tuple):
    if not selection:
        return

    # Get the actual name of the item selected
    selected_item = listbox.get(selection)

    # Replace this with what you want to do
    print(f"You selected: {selected_item}")
```

Then, when you initialize the listbox you need one more line to invoke the `on_select` callback:

```py
listbox = Listbox(ws)
listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", on_select)
```

For more information:

[About tkinter event callbacks](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/event-handlers.html) (Tells you how to write the `on_select` callback)

[About the tkinter.Listbox widget](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/listbox.html)

## Style

I think it's a great opportunity to talk about Python styles:

#### Don't redefine built-ins

On line 25 of the interface code, you wrote `list = ('Brydningsformel', 'Rydbergformel',)`. This overrides the default data structure that goes by the same name `list`. This means that if you want to use the data structure `list` in the future, such as performing list conversion, you would be unable to do it. It is better to create a more descriptive variable name that tells more about its contents, such as `listbox_items`.

Side note: The built-in identifiers are listed when you run `print(dir(__builtins__))`. Do not name any variables as such.

#### Don't use wildcard imports

Wildcard imports can be attractive if you are new, but it is not recommended unless you are in an interactive shell. Wildcard imports `from module import *` should be avoided because they pollute the global namespace - you will import a bunch of names which you don't actually need, especially for a large module. More specifically, if you name anything else as `Message`, `Scale`, `Text`, etc. in the future, you will confuse them with the tkinter classes because these names are in the `tkinter` library.

Instead, it is recommended to use `import tkinter` or `import tkinter as tk`. Then, when you actually want to use something from this module, write `tkinter.Listbox()` or `tk.Listbox()`, etc.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22903668/14426545) is a more detailed explanation.

#### Naming

For functions like `Scankey()` and `Update()`, PEP8 recommends using all lowercase. Besides, it is better to use more descriptive names than `fp()`, `v1`, `rv1`, etc.

[Here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) are the naming conventions recommended by PEP8.

#### Don't repeat

In the `Scankey()` function, you split the flow with `if val == ''`, but that isn't necessary. In Python, an empty string is automatically in any other string, so if `val=""`, then `val.lower() in item.lower()` is guaranteed to be True.

#### Docstrings

If you want to provide documentation to a function or class, it is better to use docstrings instead of comments. Docstrings are multiline strings dedicated for documentation, and they will be parsed by many IDLEs automatically. See improved code below.

#### Code

Here's my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

# The "-> None" specifies that the function will return nothing.
# Use "-> int", "-> str", etc. if the function will return something.

# "event: tk.Event" specifies that the argument "event" should be a tkinter Event.
def filter_listbox_items(event: tk.Event) -> None:
    """Filters displayed items in the Listbox."""
    val = event.widget.get()
    print(val)

    # The following is a list comprehension. It condenses the for loop into one line.
    data = [item for item in items if val.lower() in item.lower()]

    populate_listbox_items(data)

# "data: list" specifies that the argument "data" should be a list.
def populate_listbox_items(data: list) -> None:
    """Populates the listbox with a list of items.

    Args:
        data (list): The list of items.
    """
    listbox.delete(0, 'end')

    # Makes list of data
    for item in data:
        listbox.insert('end', item)

items = ('Brydningsformel', 'Rydbergformel',)

ws = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(ws)
entry.pack()
entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', filter_listbox_items)

listbox = tk.Listbox(ws)
listbox.pack()
populate_listbox_items(items)

ws.title("Formula")
ws.geometry('500x500+550+200')

ws.mainloop()
```

Don't worry if you don't know some of the terms yet, you will get to that very soon. Wish you all the best in your journey!